# Objects Detection in Scanned images: Resizing the images in YOLO (416x416) destroys the quality of the image

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am trying to train YOLO on scanned images. The problem is that resizing images to 416x416 distroys the quality of the images.

Is there any way to keep the same size of the images with YOLO ?

Comment: How do you know it destroys the image quality? Most of CNN only accepts low resolution of image

Comment: I visualized the image after the resizing.

Comment: An example of the images has a size 1525 x 614.
In fact, I have small objects in the images, I visualized the resized images(416x416) and the objects become so different, distorted and so complex to get recognized by YOLO. 

In the prediction step, I get always 0 bounding boxes detected by the algorithm. 

I thought the resizing was the reason. I am looking for ideas to fix this problem.

Comment: How small? If you visualized your image by resizing it to 416x416 you are wrong. Yolo will keep aspect ratio and Yolo originally will randomly resize your image during training if you set `random = 1` in your cfg file. Another factor that you can consider is the bounding box, you have to recalibrate your bounding box using k-means

Comment: What I mean by keep aspect ratio is, when you have 1525 x 614, yolo will resize it to  416 x 167, then it will randomly resized (can be smaller or bigger) every 10 iterations if you set `random = 1`. Anyway you can try another model such as Yolo 608 x 608